# create virtual machine manager using xen hypervisor API

Tags: api, virtual, xen

I want to create an application like virt-manager to create and manage virtual machines on ubuntu server using xen hypervisor.
so which language is more reliable and simple for doing this. and how can i access xen hypervisor API in my application?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about XCP/Citrix Xen then in Linux it's better to use C or Python or even bash.
All request are made by means of XML RPS and by simple HTTP GET requests via curl/ssh
There is an 
[Citrix SDK](http://community.citrix.com/display/xs/Download+SDKs) for this

Creating a VM is pretty simple. All you can do from console via xe is posible.
Here is simple code to create vm from template

```
 ...
 xen_vm_set *vms;
 if (!xen_vm_get_by_name_label(xen.session, &vms, template) || vms->size < 1)
{
  puts("Template lookup failed.\n");
  return (NULL);
}
else
{
  printf("Template \"%s\" found\n", template);
}
//Clone VM
xen_vm vm;
xen_vm_clone(xen.session, &vm, vms->contents[0], vm_name);
xen_vm_set_free(vms);
....
```

Please ask if you need any assistance.